# How to check if variable is a specific class in python?

Tags: python

I have a variable "myvar" that when I print out its 
`type(myvar)`

the output is:

```
<class 'my.object.kind'>
```

If I have a list of 10 variables including strings and variables of that kind.. how can I construct an if statement to check whether an object in the list "mylist" is of `<type 'my.object.kind'>`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to see if the list contains an element of type `my.object.kind`? Are you trying to get the types of all the elements of the list?

Comment: `isinstance()` is the python built-in-function that you're looking for. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: Relevant [What is the difference between type and isinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), this will return true even if it is an instance of the subclass:

```
if isinstance(x, my.object.kind)
```

Or:

```
type(x) == my.object.kind #3.x
```

If you want to test all in the list:

```
if any(isinstance(x, my.object.kind) for x in alist)
```

Comment: The post asks for a way to apply this to a list

Comment: @zhangyangyu I have `type( x )` that shows `<class 'argparse.Namespace'>` but then `type( x ) == argparse.Namespace.kind`says `*** AttributeError: type object 'Namespace' has no attribute 'kind'`

Comment: @SebMa `my.object.kind` is the class the OP has, not an attribute indicating the type. You should use `type(x) == argparse.Namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, my.object.kind), my_list_of_objects)):
    print "Found one!"
```

Comment: `map` and `lambda` are not necessary here, use a generator comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if any([isinstance(x, my.object.kind) for x in mylist]):
    print "found"
```