# How do I connect an existing singly-linked-list and a new singly-linked-list in python?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

```
def connect(self, new_sll):
    pre = self.head
    if sll is SinglyLL():
        pre = self.head
        for i in range(self.nodenumber):
            pre = pre.next
            
            if pre == None :
                for i in range(i + new_sll.nodenumber):
                    aft = pre.next
                    new = sll.head.data
                    node = Node(new)
                    node.next = aft
                    pre.next = node
                    self.nodenumber +=1

    
    else :
        raise TypeError("error")
```

I'm trying to connect an existing singly-linked-list (`sll`) and another singly-linked-list (`new_sll`).

If `new_sll`'s class type is `SinglyLL`, I want to connect `new_sll` with the existing `sll` and renew the node's number.

If `new_sll`'s class type is not `SinglyLL`, I want to show a type error

I can't solve this matter... how can I fix my code?

Comment: Don't use `is` ([Understanding the "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-the-is-operator)) and don't do `SinglyLL()` which creates _a new object_ and doesn't do "*If new_sll's class type is SinglyLL*".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if variable is a specific class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117729/how-to-check-if-variable-is-a-specific-class-in-python)

Comment: Also, the term and the tag [sll](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sll/info) means  something else, and it may be a confusing abbreviation for [singly-linked-list]. So I edited to expand the term to the full "singly-linked-list".

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- `sll is SinglyLL()` can never be true, as `SinglyLL()` creates a new list, which obviously is not the one that `sll` represents.
- Assuming that `nodenumber` is the number of nodes in the list, the condition `pre == None` is always going to be true, but then `aft = pre.next` will raise an error. As `pre` is `None`, the outer loop loses its benefit completely, and it becomes impossible to make the link
- `new = sll.head.data` is always going to get the same data, in each iteration of the loop.
- The name `sll` and `new_sll` are not the same, yet it seems the same is intended
- Raising an error with description "error" is not going to help anyone.

Here is a correction:

```
def connect(self, sll):
    if not isinstance(sll, SinglyLL):
        raise TypeError("The connect method should be called with an SinglyLL instance as argument")
    other = sll.head
    if not other:
        return
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = Node(other.data)
        other = other.next
    node = self.head
    while node.next:
        node = node.next
    while other:
        node.next = Node(other.data)
        node = node.next
        other = other.next
    self.nodenumber += sll.nodenumber
```